# User defined function for plotting many graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, user-defined-functions

I have a set of 3 data frames which contain birthrate and gdp data for 199 countries.  I want to create a function where the user can simply enter the which data frame and which country they want to graph.

Here is how I would manually do it;

```
AFG = subset(low.sub, country == "Afghanistan")

AFGplot <- ggplot(AFG,aes(US.,BirthRate)) + stat_summary(fun.AFG=mean_cl_normal) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm') + geom_point() + xlab("GDP, current US$") +
  ylab("Birthrate, cruder per 1,000 people") + ggtitle("Afghanistan's Birthrate as a Function of GDP, 2000-2011")
```

This is what I have for the function but I really don't have a good grasp yet on how to structure this so I was looking for some help;

```
grapher <- function(x,y) {
  df <- subset(x, country ==[y])
  plotter <- ggplot(x,aes(US.,BirthRate)) + stat_summary(fun.x=mean_cl_normal) +
    geom_smooth(method='lm') + geom_point() + xlab("GDP, current US$") +
    ylab("Birthrate, cruder per 1,000 people") + ggtitle("[y] Birthrate as a Function of GDP, 2000-2011")

  print plotter
  return(df)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Josh

Comment: Why are you returning `df` and not `plotter`? In your call to `ggplot`, you probably want to pass `df` and not `x`. For your title, use `ggtitle(paste(y, "Birthrate as a Function of GDP, 2000-2011"))`. Otherwise the title will literally say "[y]", not the name of the country.

Comment: Those corrections, and removing the brackets around y in the df part, fixed the problems I was having.  Thanks!

Comment: `print plotter` should throw an error. Fix that, too.